# NodeJS: runInNewContext and instanceof

Tags: node.js, instanceof

I have a script which does something like this:

```
var context = {}
vm.runInNewContext("var someFunc = function() {}", context);
console.log(typeof context.someFunc); //function
console.log(context.someFunc instanceof Function); //false
```

I do understand why the 4th line returns false: inside the new context there is a new `Function` object, which is not equal to the `Function` object in the outer context. Therefore, `context.someFunc` is not an instance of that outer `Function` object.

However, the `context.someFunc` function is used by a third-party library which uses `instanceof Function`. Since `context.someFunc` is a function, but not an instance of the `Function` in that context, the third party won't treat it as a function while it should and therefore it crashes. I tried using the following context:

```
var context = {
    "Function" : Function
}
```

but that didn't resolve my problem either.

Perhaps using `var someFunc = new Function(arg, body)` will work (haven't tested it), however I do not have full control of the code passed to `vm.runInNewContext` and therefore I can't use that solution either.

How can I let `context.someFunc instanceof Function` return true outside of the context?

Comment: Use `runInThisContext`  can avoid unexpected behavior of `instanceof`. And NOT set the `context` option for SourceTextModule() SyntheticModule()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually do exist solutions, but there's a tradeoff between completeness and performance.

1. Simply wrap the returned functions in another function:

   ```
    const context = {}
    vm.runInNewContext("var someFunc = function() {}", context);
    const someFunc = context.someFunc;
    context.someFunc = function(...args) { return someFunc.apply(this, args); }
    console.log(context.someFunc instanceof Function); //true
   ```

   This solution has (almost) no overhead, but it's not a complete solution. It works well for known functions that are exposed on the context directly, but it starts to break down in less trivial situations. E.g. getting this to work with higher order functions, maps, etc. requires a fair bit of work, and I think it's not even possible to cover all exotic combinations.
2. Use a `Proxy` to wrap functions on demand

   With a `Proxy` it's not needed to know in advance which values are exposed on the `context`, and instead functions can be wrapped on demand. This also makes it easier to deal with higher order functions, since we can recursively proxy return values & arguments. It is however quite a bit more effort to implement correctly, and it has a significant performance impact.
3. Alter the `Function` prototype in the new context

   ```
   const context = { OuterFunction : Function};
   vm.runInNewContext(`
     // setup
     Object.setPrototypeOf(Function.prototype, OuterFunction.prototype);
     //script
     const someFunc = function() {};
   `, context);
   console.log(context.someFunc instanceof Function);
   ```

   This solution makes the inner `Function` extend the outer `Function`, and as such any inner function is an instance of the outer function. However, using `setPrototypeOf` is extremely bad for performance, especially when altering an object like `Function`. So whenever possible, this should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Use same context in you have no control over thirdparty module. When I've run into similar problem, first i've tried to fix thirdparty module and submit pull request with explanation what was wrong, then I give up and switched to eval in `new Function()` instead of running in new context, which fits better with my needs.